# Decode string to HTML not working in ui-grid Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

In my UI-grid column, I am trying to decode my string to HTML. I am working in UI-Grid Angular.

Here is my string "`10-K&nbsp;&#10148;&nbsp;EX-23.1`" My output should be "10-K ➤ EX-23.1" but it shows string as it is. i have tried different solutions like using `escape()` and `['ngSanitize']` but these solutions didn't work at all in ui-grid.

Here is my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9zs8D2CK5Dz6QJWlBeZC?p=preview).

Comment: You only have to make it interpreted as HTML, no escape needed

Comment: @Hacketo can you give me the plunkr for that or any code help

Comment: looking at Hacketo answer, i think it may be useful to you: ng-bind-html="htmlString"

Comment: @deadManN Thanks it worked

Comment: Would you consider adding your Plunkr code to the question? As it stands the question does not contain enough information to investigate the problem - questions must be self-contained - and so it may be marked as off-topic. If you can fix it up, it would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My problem has been solved. you can achieve this thing by using `ng-bind-html="htmlString"`. you only just need to change the celltemplate like this

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-bind-html="COL_FIELD"></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried several things, as your model is on the go :D i mean is made using library, and is not build over your HTML, i change your model
http://plnkr.co/edit/xMIwKxiNvkPLUPrRKt5o?p=preview

as you can find out i used this:

```
angular.element('<div />').html("10-K&nbsp;&#10148;&nbsp;EX-23.1").text()
```

here you go

next thing you need is to iterate through your model, and replace your incoming data with new data, which is parsed using that method

Answer (score 0):

If we are trying to render the element which is coming from server as html-string in a row.entity way, follow the code below

```
header.cellTemplate = '<div ng-bind-html="row.entity.attribute"></div>';
```

or if we just want to render the html-string, instead of row.entity.attribute user the html-string as below

```
header.cellTemplate = '<div ng-bind-html="html-string"></div>';
```